# ContinueWith method isn't waiting until the Asyncronous Task is completed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to log requests and responses to the API. I am currently using a delegatingHandler  which catches the httpwebresponses and httpwebrequests.

Handler:

```
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        LogRequest(request);
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith((task) =>
             {
                 HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;
                 LogResponse(response);
                 return response;
             });
    }
```

LogResponse:

```
    private void LogResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        ApiResponse info = new ApiResponse();
        //Populate response obj   

        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((task) =>
                    { 
                        info.Content = task.Result;
                    }
                );
        }
        _repository.LogResponse(info);
    }
```

I am getting an null exception when i try to insert the Content into the database in my repository. But when i step through to the content object its populated with the response. I'm thinking I am trying to insert the data into the DB before the request has finished.

I dont want to wait for it because that defeats the purpose of using asynchronous requests, how can i hook it up to run the logresponse method when the requests completed? I thought the continueWith took care of this and runs the action when the task is completed (does this mean that the downloading of the request isnt necessarily finished though?).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try debug prints to see the code flow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting `info.Content` asynchronously to the call to `_repository.LogResponse(info)`.  `LogResponse` is likely called before the continuation is even executed.  Move your call to `LogResponse` within the continuation's body.  For example:

```
if (response.Content != null)
{
    response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((task) =>
            { 
                info.Content = task.Result;
                _repository.LogResponse(info);
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: New to asynchronous programming and errors like these are catching me out atm!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (response.Content != null)
{
    var task = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((task) =>
                       { 
                           info.Content = task.Result;
                       });

    task.Wait();
}

_repository.LogResponse(info);
```

Comment: True. You either wait for it to finish, or you log to repository inside your task, at the end of it. The point is that the code has to be run thoroughly before logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example:

```
private void LogResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    ApiResponse info = new ApiResponse();
    //Populate response obj   

    if (response.Content != null)
    {
        var info = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        _repository.LogResponse(info);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doubtful the op is using VS 11

Comment: This is avaliable with VS 2010 too

Comment: Not a lot of people can use "unsupported and use-at-your-own-risk Technology Preview"